# How do I get running total for distinct values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cumulative-sum

I'd like to group by date range as the below example

```
    Date        ItemNo  Qty
==================================
1/1/2014         101    20
2/1/2014         102    10
3/1/2014         103    5
4/1/2014         104    10
1/1/2014         101    5
2/1/2014         101    10
3/1/2014         102    15
4/1/2014         104    20
```

I want to get the balance daily by sum the qty till that day grouped by ItemNo to be as below

```
Date        ItemNo  Qty
==================================
1/1/2014      101   25
2/1/2014      101   35
2/1/2014      102   10
3/1/2014      102   25
3/1/2014      103   5
4/1/2014      104   30
```

I know I can solve the problem by using cursors but I need another solution

thanks

Comment: Do you mean that your Date column is actually a DateTime column - and you want to group by just the date portion of it?

Comment: No , I want to group by date but each group sum all previous quantities

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals @Ahmed Fayed

Answer (score 2):

so just use SUM

```
SELECT Date, ItemNo, SUM(Qty)
FROM table
GROUP BY Date, ItemNo
```

please read on [agregate function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp) and [sum](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php)

### Edit

i took your comment and did this:

```
SELECT a.Date, a.ItemNo, tmp.qty + a.ItemNo
FROM table a
JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table t WHERE t.date < a.Date ORDER BY t.date DESC) tmp ON a.ItemNo = tmp.ItemNo
```

i'm checking it now, so it might need some tweaks, but i wanted to release it straight away so you'll have the general idea

Comment: I want to group till date not for specific date . I mean Item x balance is 5 yesterday and today is 10 then the statement will return 5 for yesterday and 15 for today

Comment: @AhmedFayed but does it gives you the idea for witch path should you go?

Answer (score 2):

Here is your sample table

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM
(
SELECT  '1/1/2014' [DATE],         101 [ItemNo],    20 QTY
UNION ALL
SELECT '2/1/2014',         102,    10
UNION ALL
SELECT '3/1/2014',         103,    5
UNION ALL
SELECT '4/1/2014',         104,    10
UNION ALL
SELECT '1/1/2014',         101,    5
UNION ALL
SELECT '2/1/2014',        101,    10
UNION ALL
SELECT '3/1/2014',         102,    15
UNION ALL
SELECT '4/1/2014',         104,    20
)TAB
```

Use `Row_Number` to get number for each Item's date do the `sum` inside `CTE`

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  [ItemNo] ORDER BY CAST([DATE] AS DATE))RNO,
    [DATE],[ItemNo],SUM(Qty)Qty
    FROM #TEMP
    GROUP BY [DATE],[ItemNo]
)
SELECT A.RNO,[DATE],[ItemNo],
CASE WHEN RNO=1 THEN Qty 
     ELSE (SELECT SUM(b.Qty)
           FROM   CTE1 b
           WHERE  A.ItemNo=B.ItemNo AND B.RNO<=A.RNO) 
END QTY
FROM CTE1 A
ORDER  BY A.itemno,CAST(A.[DATE] AS DATE);
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: That seems a solution but it took more than 3 hours running and sql crashed then . I need an optimized solution as Cursor would take less time but I didn't use it because of performance

Comment: Yes. Absolutely it will take time. If you are dealing with such a huge table its better you can keep a column to store cumulative value(running total) so that in the future it will be easy to query from the table.
If you are using cursor, it will be fast than the above query since there is no need to query and find the sum for each record since variables can keep the value on each loop of cursor execution, but its not advisable to use cursor for such a large table. @Ahmed Fayed

Comment: Do I need to write cursor query for you? @Ahmed Fayed

Comment: If you are getting the answer for the question you have asked(ie, query without using cursor), you can mark this as the answer so that the next one who need this type of answer can easily identify it @Ahmed Fayed

Comment: I need a faster solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a recursive common table expression.

Not sure if it will be faster or not than the answer by Sarath Avanavu, but you can try!

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE([Date] DATETIME, ItemNo INT, QTY INT)
INSERT @t
        ( Date, ItemNo, QTY )
          SELECT  '1/1/2014',         101,    20
UNION ALL SELECT '2/1/2014',         102,    10
UNION ALL SELECT '3/1/2014',         103,    5
UNION ALL SELECT '4/1/2014',         104,    10
UNION ALL SELECT '1/1/2014',         101,    5
UNION ALL SELECT '2/1/2014',        101,    10
UNION ALL SELECT '3/1/2014',         102,    15
UNION ALL SELECT '4/1/2014',         104,    20
```

Query:

```
;WITH dSum AS (
    SELECT [Date], ItemNo, SUM(QTY) AS QTY 
    FROM @t AS t
    GROUP BY [Date], [ItemNo]
), dSumRN AS (
    SELECT [Date], ItemNo, QTY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ItemNo ORDER BY [Date]) AS rn 
    FROM dSum
), cte AS (
        SELECT [Date], ItemNo, QTY, rn
        FROM  dSumRN
        WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL SELECT
        dSumRN.[Date], dSumRN.ItemNo, cte.QTY + dSumRN.QTY AS QTY, cte.rn + 1 AS rn
    FROM cte
        JOIN dSumRN ON cte.ItemNo = dSumRN.ItemNo AND cte.rn + 1 = dSumRN.rn

)
SELECT [Date], [ItemNo], QTY FROM cte
ORDER BY [Date], [ItemNo]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000) -- maximum this can be set to is 32767
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest code below for your query:

```
select Date,itemno,
(select sum(Qty) from #temp where date<=T.date and itemno=T.itemno)
from #temp T 
group by Date,itemno order by date
```